# How can I disable interface smoothing of point clouds in 2.9?

Tags: interface, point-clouds

I am working with point clouds and for a greater precision need to match viewport's point drawing of Blender 2.91 to 2.79.

Here is a comparison between them (Object mode):

[image]

As you can see newer version is much bulkier due to outlining or extra smoothing.

In preferences I totally disabled antialiasing and set "Thin" line width.